# Highlight a specific div on click to attract attention

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a site and i haven't been able to figure out how to highlight a certain div without everything blowing out of proportion. I want the top nav where it says home, sitemap, and contact to highlight a div in the footer. When you click contact i want it have you dragged down to the bottom where it is but i want it to highlight the contact div just to get your attention real quick so its easier to find. i tried some plugins but they didnt work to well.

[Site](http://jsfiddle.net/h7wRH/)

```
 <div id="navContainer">
<div id="nav">
    <ul>

        <li><a href="index.html" class="scroll nav">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#footer" class="scroll nav">Site Map</a></li>
        <li><a href="#footer" class="scroll nav">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, add an id to the contact button like `contact` and one to the `ul` like `contactUL` then this works. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/h7wRH/1/)

```
$("#contacter").click(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop($(document).height());
    $("#contact").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

Comment: The OP didn't mention anything about jQuery. Is there a way to do this without it?

Comment: Updated, see jsFiddle. I noticed you already had a contact id, so I changed the names to fit

Comment: yes yes pretty much this. wrongs places but i think i could figure it out haha. thanks man

Comment: and now it explodes all other javascript away haha. hmm

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:
http://jsfiddle.net/E6h5u/1

```
// on click of a nav element with class scroll
$('nav .scroll').click(function () {
    // select the corresponding footer element 
    // (you may want to work with a class or data attribute, in stead of basing on the content)
    var $footer = $('footer a:contains(' + $(this).text() + ')');
    // scroll to it
    $("body").animate({
        scrollTop: $footer.offset().top
    }, "slow", function () {
        // when the scroll is ready, add a highlight class
        $footer.addClass('highlight');
        // wait some, and remove the class again
        setTimeout(function() { $footer.removeClass('highlight'); }, 1000);
    });
});
```

I put the explanation in the code comments, but feel free to ask.

Note that I used a class with a css transition for the highlighting, but you could also use some jQuery animation if you prefer (for legacy browser compatibility with the css transition perhaps...)

Answer (score 0):

Gotta use javascript (and preferably JQuery, as the previous poster said).  Here is a working Fiddle showing how you could could go about this.

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrLoop/eBxyM/1/

```
$('#nav ul li:nth-child(3) a').click(function(){
    $('#footer .contact').addClass('highlight');
});
```